# Starting a traversal from nodes having Labels (Traversal framework)

Tags: neo4j, traversal

In my current model, I'm using the Traversal framework to perform queries starting from a specific node.

```
(Node{id:"XXX"}) -> ...Other nodes.
```

For economy reasons (to reduce the number of used nodes and relationships), I'm thinking about adding the Label "XXX" to the Other nodes.

Knowing that Other nodes can be some million of nodes, I'm wondering if :
- It's a good or bad idea to model it this way (independtly of being more economic)?
- Using the Traversal framework in this case, how should I specify the starting node?

**Edit** :

A concrete example:

Let's suppose I have User nodes of type Person (Node:Person). Each Person node is related to a Country node (Node:Country) with the relationship :LIVES_IN
Each Person can be linked to 0..* Persons with the relationship :KNOWS

I'm using the traversal framework to find, in 1 country, distinct groups of Person which are connected between each other (directly or indirectly). I'm doing this by starting the traversal from the country node and traversing the LIVES_IN and KNOWS relationships.

Person living in the same country, as you could imagine, can reach some millions.

Answer (score 0):

You should always try to come/look from the side with the fewer relationships of this type and direction.

So depending if you have fewer relationships on the right or left side I'd come from that smaller side.

You can also have a look at the bidirectional traversal api, which progresses simultaneously from both sides until it finds an overlap.

In your concrete example I would always look from the person side, and just check that they are in the same country, i.e. the node on the other end of the lives_in relationship is the same country node.

So I'd correlate people via other means first (where you have to deal with fewer rels) and only then check the country.

Another option is to substructure the lives-in relationship into states/counties and cities.

Then you have only a few thousand relationships from country to city, and depending on your model also just a few thousand from city to person. So you can check the city first on both sides, and either they are in the same city, or you'd just check that the two cities are in the same country.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your answer, but I'm not sure I got the 1st part of it. I've added a concrete example on the original post.